# Can I install Ubuntu on second HDD without grub?

Tags: dual-boot

I have a 500gb SSD that has windows, and another 1TB HDD that I want Ubuntu on. How can I make it so that Ubuntu is installed on the HDD without GRUB (As my keyboard needs to be set into BIOS mode first which is annoying), and just be able to boot to Ubuntu like I would boot to a USB?

Comment: How do you set your keyboard to BIOS mode? Do you mean you installed Ubuntu in Legacy mode and Windows in UEFI mode?

Comment: I have a K55 Keyboard, which has a lot of other keys and stuff, and for some reason I have to switch to BIOS mode to do anything. I switch by hitting F1 and the WinLock key at the same time for 10 seconds.

Comment: What brand/model system? May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  It seems like you have to switch boot modes UEFI/BIOS when booting. That should not be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot** install Ubuntu without GRUB, because GRUB is the bootloader for Ubuntu. What you can do however, is perform a manual installation and tell it to install GRUB to the HDD instead of to the SSD with Windows. Then you could customize the GRUB configuration to make it automatically boot Ubuntu instead of showing the menu. That would result in very similar behavior to what you want. (Switching OSes by switching the boot device / boot order)

Comment: Could you explain how to install GRUB to the HDD instead of the SSD? Also how would I customize it to do the intended behavior?

Comment: @Sxribe so as far as installing GRUB to the HDD, at the bottom of the [manual partitioning screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DBJC.png) there's a box to select which drive you want to install GRUB to. I'm assuming your SSD will probably be `/dev/sda`, which means your HDD will probably be `/dev/sdb`.

Comment: @Sxribe now regarding making GRUB automatically boot Ubuntu, you can do that by editing `/etc/default/grub` and changing the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` parameter to `0`, and then running `sudo update-grub`